# Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, integration

I've updated to the new Xcode 6.1 and server 4.0. I was able to get continuous integration on the simulators but not the devices in the previous version. Now that I've updated, I'm not getting any continuous integration. I'm getting the following 2 errors:

> Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long
>
> The xcodebuild task completed with uncaught signal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have this happening all of a sudden now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When I changed my signing certificate on my Xcode CI machine I could see that the bots got stuck on signing the build products.

Checking running processes on the Xcode CI machine showed me what executable was trying to access my signing certificate

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 043...DE2A --entitlements /Library/Develop...
```

I opened Keychain and found my signing certificate in the `System` keychain, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to show info and added `codesign` to the list of executables that could access it without authenticating.

[image]

Comment: This solved the same error I was getting during archiving. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You save my ass today, I was stuck with this for 2 day. Thanks man.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. So, I ran into an issue where making any changes to the key wouldn't take. It seemed to accept the change, but then when I opened it again, the change reverted. I found that when I made the change (either adding the app as you did or just choosing "Allow all applications..." ) and then click "Save Changes" followed by an immediate Command-Q to quit the app, the change would take. Not sure why. Maybe it's just my computer/keychain. Anyhow thanks again for the answer here. Would've been scratching my head without it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) . Need to select a secret key (LastName FirstName) in keychain for this window and then press cmd+i.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my error. All my signing certs have checked “Allow all applications ...” and it does not work

Comment: How did you check what the running processes were accessing?

Comment: I think I might have used the "lsof"

Answer (score 4):

In my case, we use Crashlytics in our project, which contains a run script to run Crashlytics framework after build:

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This script will hang the Xcode server bot.

After removing the script (or create another scheme without any run script for Xcode server bot), it works again.

Watch out any run script in your project scheme.

Comment: where you find this crashlytics script ?, i have used crashlytics in my project and got same issue for Xcode bot. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

How many devices/simulators are you testing against? Try cutting it back to one simulator, and seeing if it completes.

Comment: I did. I cut it all the way back to 1 simulator and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to this problem was to open Xcode on my server, go to Preferences -> Accounts and make sure that it had downloaded all my provisioning profiles.