# Xcode - Bot produced no output for too long followed by status 15 failure

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots, osx-server

I have a Bot running, and it worked just fine until I updated my Provisioning Profile, and copied the new one into the XcodeServer/Provisioning Profiles folder. Now I get the following errors:

First, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879391/terminated-xcodebuild-since-it-produced-no-output-for-too-long) question (I don't have anything special in my project):

Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error.
Issue: Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long..
Integration Number: 1.
Integration URL: https://buildserver.example.com/xcode/bots/F3AF171/integrations
Description: Terminated xcodebuild since it produced no output for too long..

Followed by:

Bot Issue: warning. Build Service Error.
Issue: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 15..
Integration Number: 1.
Integration URL: https://buildserver.example.com/xcode/bots/F3AF171/integrations
Description: Creating archive failed: xcodebuild exited with status 15..

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was adding codesign to my private key. For some reason, and I don't know how, it was removed as allow access on my private key for my release certificate private key. It was still there on my development certificate. It is the second answer by Niels Castle in the linked question.

Comment: How do I find the specific key, what is the name of the key in the keychain?